# Why is a 3rd variable necessary in this arithmetic progression sum’s code?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

Why do I need a local variable `result` in this code? I guess I'm having an infinite loop when I try to use only 2 variables, but I don't get how to recognize this issue in the code and use debug to understand the issue.

# Write a method that takes in an integer `num` and returns the sum of
    # all integers between zero and num, up to and including `num`.

```
def sum_nums(num)
  result = 0

  i = 0
  while i <= num
    result += i
    i += 1
  end

  return result
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in order for this code to work, you need to know three things: the number you are counting up to (`num`), the current value of the number (`i`), and the current sum from 0 to `i`. `result` is the variable keeping track of the sum from 0 to `i`.

However, this isn't a very ruby way of writing this method. `while` loops are meant to be used in situations where you don't know how many times you need to loop. In this case, you know the number of loops, so an iterator is better for this purpose.

```
def sum_nums(num)
  (0..num).reduce(:+)
end
```

The above method will return the same result as your method.

Comment: fwiw the & is redundant in the reduce call, I agree with the point you're making though.

Comment: Restating the question in the answer isn't necessary and adds confusion as you haven't changed anything there. The `reduce` solution should be the first thing you talk about as that's the correct answer. State your best answer up front, and justify or explain it afterwards. I'd also delete the part about recursion as that's an anti-pattern. Something like that will blow up on non-trivial sized numbers.

Answer (score 4):

In your function you use three variables:

**num** which holds the range over which you want to do the summing (or the number of times you need to loop)

**i** which holds the specific integer you are adding to the sum within each loop

**result** which holds the sum so far (and at the end of the final loop, holds the answer you want). Without this variable, the next loop would 'lose track' of how  much all the previous loops had already added to the sum of integers.

You could get rid of the **i** variable as follows

```
result = 0
while num > 0 
  result += 1
  num -= 1
end
return result
```

This relies on the fact that if you count down from num you know to stop at 0. Alternately you could get rid of both the **i** variable and the **result** variable as follows

```
return num*(num+1)/2
```

This relies on an algebraic formula for the sum of integers rather than explicitly carrying out the sum. Both of these snippets will produce the same return as your function.

In summary, you need the num variable, otherwise your function won't 'know' what range to do the sum over. You can get away without the i variable (but the meaning of the code may not be so obvious), but you can only get away without the result variable if you can find a method that doesn't need the loop.

Comment: Great answer in the form of a simple calculation vs. a long, drawn out series of addition operations, but the `return` is not necessary. It's implicit in Ruby.

Comment: @tadman - thanks for the comment. I am not really familiar with Ruby, so consider my code clips as algorithmic pseudo-code.